# 自作クラス内でクラス名と同じ型を持つフィールドに対して値を設定するには

Tags: c#

自作クラス内でクラス名と同じ型を持つフィールドに対し、値を設定するにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？
作成したいもののイメージとしては、System.Windows.Automation 名前空間の ControlType クラスのようなものを自作したいと考えており、以下のコードはそのソースを参考にして作成したものです。
無理にキャストしてみたりして、Type.type1 が null にならないように試みてみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。

```
class Type : TypeIdentifier
{
    public static readonly Type type1;
    public static readonly Type type2;
    public static readonly Type type3;

    static Type()
    {
        type1 = (Type)0x01; // エラー CS0029
        type2 = (Type)0x02; // エラー CS0029
        type3 = (Type)0x03; // エラー CS0029
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type type = Type.type1; // null
        Console.WriteLine(type.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(type.ProgrammaticName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeIdentifier`の定義が開示されていないので確実とは言えませんが、`null`以外にしたいのであれば、とりあえず、`type1 = new Type();`とは書けそうです。

現実に値を持つ`Type`インスタンスを生成したい場合は、`Type`クラスにコンストラクタを作る必要があるでしょう。

```
static Type()
{
  type1 = new Type(0x01);
  type2 = new Type(0x02);
  type3 = (Type)0x03; // explicit operator Type(int)の実装が必要
}

public Type(int value)
{
  // TypeIdentifierのIdが代入可能な場合
  Id = value;

  // { get; } のみ、privateなど、継承クラスから変更ができないようにする・している場合は
  // public Type(int value) : base(value) { } というように基底クラスコンストラクタ
  // 呼び出しを書く。
}

// int型からの明示キャストを実現したいならexplicit、暗黙ならimplicitで
// operator Type(int)を定義する
public static explicit operator Type(int value)
{
  return new Type(value);
}
```